# Replace text in PDF file using iTextSharp(not AcroFields)

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am working on iTextSharp with asp.net C# to create PDF files.
I created many reports(pdfs) using iTextSharp and all works well.
Now my client gave me pre-formatted pdf file in which there are some text which need to be replaced with database values.

Now I want to replace text in existing pdf file and create new one.
But as I googled, it is not possible in iTextSharp.

I have some questions now
Is it really not possible to replace text in pdf using iTextSharp?
Is there any other library or third party tool(free-no licence required) which does so?
If so, please give me some suggestion on it.

For your info, I don't have AcroFields in pdf files and also heard about ASPOSE - PDF File format APIs (which is not free).

Comment: Look at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wxGEEv7ibHE and discover what text looks like inside a PDF. Depending on your reports, it may be feasible to replace text in a PDF (although such a design is flawed: it's *not done*), or completely impossible. I'm going to vote to close this question because you're asking to recommend a tool or library (and that's off-topic on StackOverflow).

Comment: I just wanted to know how to replace text in PDF? if it's not possible using iTextSharp, then i am asking for any other library which is free?

Comment: Whether or not it's possible depends entirely upon the PDF, not on the tool you use (maybe you didn't watch the move, or you didn't understand its message). Asking for another library is not allowed on StackOverflow (it's one of the bullets you can select as a reason to close a question). Moreover: it is useless to ask for such a library. Read the intro of http://manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf

Comment: I read this chapter. I know everything whatever you are talking about PDF, but one of my colleague-friend using PDFLib which replaces text in PDF. So I asked about that kind of help

Comment: Maybe the PDF he's talking about allows text replacement, but you're asking for a library that can replace text *in general*. Even PDFLib can't do that.

Comment: For reference, directly from PDFlib on how the `search_and_replace_text` function works: _"Find text with TET, hide it with a white rectangle, and add the replacement text on top of it"_. http://www.pdflib.com/tet-cookbook/tet-and-pdflib/search-and-replace-text/

Answer (score 4):

NO  you cannot replace the existing text with iText.

PDF is a display format, so when the PDF is rendered many decisions are made about page and character 
layout and positioning.PDF document is not a Word document as such.

Comment: +1 because that's exactly what I tried to explain. Unfortunately, the OP doesn't want to believe me because he knows somebody who was able to replace text in a specific PDF using a specific library. I'm pretty sure iTextSharp can be used to replace text in that PDF too, but evenso: (1) the design of an application that replaces words in a content stream as described is bad, and (2) the OP assumes that free software is completely gratis, which isn't true: http://itextpdf.com/salesfaq (and also http://www.openhealthnews.com/articles/2014/heartbleed-apache-license-business-model-failure )